# How can I change the port of Remote Desktop?

Tags: networking, remote-desktop, vnc

How can I change the port of Ubuntu's built in Remote Desktop?

Comment: What Ubuntu release are you running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Ubuntu 12.04 you can do that via the `gsettings` command. This changes the port to `1234`:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.Vino alternative-port 1234
gsettings set org.gnome.Vino use-alternative-port true
```

To see all the options for Vino:

```
gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.Vino
```